# Expand vector positionally based on another vector (vectorised)

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way to speed this process up. I have two types of vector, x, my reference vector and y my data holding vector.

```
x <- rep(c(0,1), 25)

y <- rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 8)
```

I need it so that if x == 0, then the output is NA but if x = 1 then the output is y.

I currently have:

```
out <- character(50)

count <- 0
count2 <- 0 

for(i in x) {
  count <- count + 1
  if (i == 1) {
    count2 <- count2 + 1
    out[count] <- y[count2]
  }
  else{
    out[count] <- NA
  }
}

Intended_out <- c(NA, "a", NA, "b", NA, "c", NA, "a", NA, "b", NA, "c", NA, "a", NA, "b", NA, "c", NA, "a", NA, "b", NA, "c", NA, "a", NA, "b", 
NA, "c", NA, "a", NA, "b", NA, "c", NA, "a", NA, "b", NA, "c", 
NA, "a", NA, "b", NA, "c", NA, NA)
```

x = 0 is used to show where a gap needs to be filled in y, x = 1 indicates that y should be used. The first 1 represents the first element in y, the second 1 indicates the second y element etc. The output should end up the same length as x, with all the y values in the same order, but gaps filled with NA where x = 0.

This does what I need, but I can't think of a way to do this at scale. I have lots of y vectors, which are all different, but the same length. x always stays the same and always greater than y. Is there a way to vectorise this process?  It would be great if I can just bind all the y's in a dataframe, preferably in a pipeable way, and then apply this logic to the whole data frame but my brain has given up at this point.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for `ifelse(x == 0, NA, y)`?

Comment: Do you mean within a mutate function? X is always greater than y, so they can't be in the same dataframe. Should of put that in the description,  I will edit.

Comment: Do `z <- x; length(z) <- length(y)` and then `ifelse(z == 0, NA, y)`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, this leaves me with a smaller vector, I need the vector to be the same size as x, but containing the info from y where x = 1.

Comment: OK? Then just switch it around and adjust the length of `y` to have the same length of `x` before using `ifelse`.

Comment: haha good point, as I menitoned my brain is giving up for the day... I have just tried this, for some reason instead of NA, a, NA, b, NA, c, I'm getting NA, b, NA, a, NA, c. I'm not sure why its messing with the order like that.

Comment: you never gave the intended solution, but `NA, b, NA a, NA, c` is the correct order if using the vector y asgiven. ie, the first value 0 corresponds to first a, thus NA, then second value in y is b, which corresponds to 1 in vector x, thus maintained.. so on

Comment: the last `1`in `x` has no corresonding value in `y`. why did you output it as `NA` instead of maintaining it as `1`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I've added an edit to the question. Hopefully this clears it up a bit.

Comment: why did you change the last 1 to NA? notice that there are 25 1's yet you have 24 valus in y. you replaced everything but the last 1 you changed it to NA why?

Comment: That's my bad quick example. Its NA because there is no Y element to reference at that position, it has already captured all the Y values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
> y[cumsum(x) * NA^(1 - x)]
 [1] NA  "a" NA  "b" NA  "c" NA  "a" NA  "b" NA  "c" NA  "a" NA  "b" NA  "c" NA 
[20] "a" NA  "b" NA  "c" NA  "a" NA  "b" NA  "c" NA  "a" NA  "b" NA  "c" NA  "a"
[39] NA  "b" NA  "c" NA  "a" NA  "b" NA  "c" NA  NA
```

Answer (score 1):

If the length of the vectors is <=100, you could also use `pmatch`:

```
y[pmatch(x,x[x==1])]
 [1] NA  "a" NA  "b" NA  "c" NA  "a" NA  "b" NA  "c" NA  "a" NA  "b" NA  "c" NA  "a"
[21] NA  "b" NA  "c" NA  "a" NA  "b" NA  "c" NA  "a" NA  "b" NA  "c" NA  "a" NA  "b"
[41] NA  "c" NA  "a" NA  "b" NA  "c" NA  NA
```

Comment: Thanks this works fine, but I unfortunately some will be over 100